# Program to respond to Whatsapp messages

Tags: python, automation, whatsapp

I need a program that detects a whatsapp message, and depending on what the message says it replies with a something different. Does anyone have any idea or code that will help me go about making this program with python?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available in order to build a WhatsApp bot using Python, however take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-whatsapp-chatbot-with-python-flask-and-twilio), which is simple and gets you up and running.